# Laravel Spatie backup save to s3 folder without creating subdirectory

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, backup

I have spatie/laravel-backup v8.1.7 and I want to save to a s3 folder named `backups`

To acheive this in filesystems.php I've added the following:

```
'backups' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'root' => 'backups', // specify the root directory for backups
 ],
```

In backup.php config file under destination I have:

```
'destination' => [

        'filename_prefix' => 'backup_',

        'disks' => [
            'backups',
        ],
      
],
```

Now when it get saved to s3, it seems to first create a subdirectory using the `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup'),` config variable and inside that it creates the backup file e.g. `backups/laravel-backup/backup_2023-03-03-14-41-58.zip`

How do i configure it so that is creates the backup directly in the s3 backup folder without creating a further subdirectory e.g. `backups/backup_2023-03-03-14-41-58.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve by simply renaming the following variable:

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'laravel-backup')
```

To

```
'name' => env('BACKUP_FOLDER', 'backups')
```

This way i don't need to configure the backup disk in the filesystem.php file either - I can just use my existing s3 configuration that already defined in there.